# The Closure in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, closures, zend-framework2

When I read the  Zend\MVC\Service\ServiceManagerConfig.php in ZF2. I get a problem. Here is the code:

```
$serviceManager->addInitializer(function ($instance) use ($serviceManager) {
        if ($instance instanceof EventManagerAwareInterface
            && !$instance->getEventManager() instanceof EventManagerInterface
        ) {
            $instance->setEventManager($serviceManager->get('EventManager'));
        }
    });
```

I know that there is a closure in the method "addInitializer".But what makes me confused is the parameter "$instance". It's a parameter but where is the real value from ? var_dump() of $instance and find that it's a object,that's "Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ServiceListener" ; Where does it come in ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `$sm->get('something');` object will be created using defined factories and then passed to initializers. `$instance` parameter is that object.

You can see that [here](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php#L518)

Comment: Yes,That's the answer.Thank you.